# NGRX Entity - how to handle isSelected property properly?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I have a table where each row might be clicked and then it should change a color and later on be used to filter out selected items. In each row I have an item:

```
interface Item{
   id:string;
   name:string;
   price:number;
}
```

I am wondering what is a better approach regarding EntityStateAdapter:

1. add `isSelected` property to `Item` and later on updating this part of state?

OR

2. extend Adapter state and store selected items in array.

```
export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Item> = createEntityAdapter<Item>();

export const initialState: EntityState<Item> = adapter.getInitialState({
        selectedItems:Array<string>
})
```

IMO 1st approach is better. It is easier to just add property to Item, because later on I can easily reflect the state in table for each row just by `item.isSelected`. I would like to hear about your experience.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `selectedItems`, reasons:

- it's "meta data" that is added on top of an entity
- easier to update, e.g. if you select or unselect you can simply update the array instead of looking the entity up before you can update it